# Converting multiple PDF's to Text files with PDFminer3

Tags: python-3.x, pdfminer

Hopefully this is a pretty easy one, but I am brand new to using python 3 for a small project and would like some guidance. I have a folder of over 1000 pdf documents with some data I would like to extract. I can successfully convert a PDF to a text file and save it in the scripts directory, however I cant figure out how to have this run for all of the PDFs at once and create an output file for each in a new folder. The code I have so far is below.

```
from pdfminer3.layout import LAParams, LTTextBox
from pdfminer3.pdfpage import PDFPage
from pdfminer3.pdfinterp import PDFResourceManager
from pdfminer3.pdfinterp import PDFPageInterpreter
from pdfminer3.converter import PDFPageAggregator
from pdfminer3.converter import TextConverter
import io

resource_manager = PDFResourceManager()
fake_file_handle = io.StringIO()
converter = TextConverter(resource_manager, fake_file_handle)
page_interpreter = PDFPageInterpreter(resource_manager, converter)

with open('/sample/mypdf.pdf', 'rb') as fh:

    for page in PDFPage.get_pages(fh,
                                  caching=True,
                                  check_extractable=True):
        page_interpreter.process_page(page)

    text = fake_file_handle.getvalue()

# close open handles
converter.close()
fake_file_handle.close()

print(text, file=open("Output.txt","a"))
```

I would appreciate any help or direction as how I can move forward. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways I can think of. If you wish to do it for a few files. You can append all your file paths into a list as follows. and iterate through it. Same function but just iterate it from a list. For example,

```
list = ["C:\\Users\\blabla\\Desktop\\.pdf\\test.pdf"
        ,"C:\\Users\\blabla\\Desktop\\.pdf\\testmore.pdf"
        ,"C:\\Users\\blabla\\Desktop\\.pdf\\writingtoxml.pdf"
        ,"C:\\Users\\blabla\Desktop\\.pdf\\2Data.pdf"]
for pathname in list:
    #your code goes here
```

Or else, you could iterate from a given directory. Place all your documents in one folder, specify the directory as follows and iterate through. If you wish for a different output name for every file, rename them.

```
import os
directory = "C:\\Users\\blabla\\Desktop\\.pdf"
for filename in os.listdir(directory):
    if filename.endswith(".pdf"):
        pathname = os.path.join(directory, filename)
        #Your code goes here
        continue
    else:
        continue
```

The only part you have to change in your code is replacing this part:

```
with open('/sample/mypdf.pdf', 'rb') as fh:
```

with this:

```
with open(pathname, 'rb') as fh:
```

Because `pathname` itself prints out the paths that you want as follows:

```
C:\Users\blabla\Desktop\.pdf\test.pdf
C:\Users\blabla\Desktop\.pdf\testmore.pdf
C:\Users\blabla\Desktop\.pdf\writingtoxml.pdf
C:\Users\blabla\Desktop\.pdf\2Data.pdf
```

Comment: Also use the os.mkdir to make new folders

Answer (score 0):

This post was so helpful! I know it's from a few years ago, but just in case someone else out there is trying to figure out how to do this, I'm adding a bit to Han's code.

Below is how I figured out how to extract and then append the text to new files in a directory. This is my first time posting, so sorry if I've missed some etiquette!

```
from pdfminer3.layout import LAParams, LTTextBox
from pdfminer3.pdfpage import PDFPage
from pdfminer3.pdfinterp import PDFResourceManager
from pdfminer3.pdfinterp import PDFPageInterpreter
from pdfminer3.converter import PDFPageAggregator
from pdfminer3.converter import TextConverter
import io
from io import StringIO
import glob
import os

rsrcmgr = PDFResourceManager()
sio = StringIO()
codec = "utf-8"
laparams = LAParams()
converter = TextConverter(rsrcmgr, sio, codec=codec, laparams=laparams)
interpreter = PDFPageInterpreter(rsrcmgr, converter)

directory_path = "D:/User/ToyDir"
directory = directory = glob.glob(f"{directory_path}/**/*.pdf", recursive=True)
outputDir = "D:/User/NewToyDir"

for pathname in directory:
    with open(pathname, 'rb') as fh:
        for page in PDFPage.get_pages(fh,
                                    caching=True,
                                    check_extractable=True):
            interpreter.process_page(page)
        text = sio.getvalue()
        #print(text)
        bareName = os.path.split(pathname)[1]
        bareName = bareName[:-3] +".txt"
        newName = os.path.join(outputDir, bareName)
        with open(newName, "a") as o:
            o.write(text)
```